# IntelliJ 13 cannot import maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am running IntelliJ 13 (the latest version) on Mac Mavericks. IntelliJ had been working well until yesterday when I found it got stuck when importing maven projects.

I created maven projects by using "mvn archetype:generate". IntelliJ is stuck at the following screen captured: No matter how many times I click the "Next" button or how long I wait, nothing shows up.

I've done a search on google, and have enabled IPv4 for maven per some answers I found, however, this does not work for me. I think my problem is caused by something different.  So what could be wrong? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to search for projects recursively?  Are you sure that the project's top level (that is, a pom.xml and src/ folder) are at that exact location?

Comment: yes, have tried that as well, but still does not work. thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed that the project is correctly generated, by running mvn clean install on the command line? If that works, confirm that idea has the same version of maven configured as the command line.

Comment: Forking command line: /bin/sh -c cd /Users/tonywang/Desktop/java/rcholic-app && /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -jar /Users/tonywang/Desktop/java/rcholic-app/target/surefire/surefirebooter3930971507545075713.jar /Users/tonywang/Desktop/java/rcholic-app/target/surefire/surefire505896429633188628tmp /Users/tonywang/Desktop/java/rcholic-app/target/surefire/surefire_05578957505219101494tmp
Running com.rcholic.app.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: above is the result of running "mvn clean install", no failures.

Comment: Have you tried `open project` on the pom, rather than import project?

Comment: The root directory in the image above is different from the one on your command line. Is there a synonym connecting the two, or are these really different? The project root in intellij needs to be the same one you run mvn from.

Comment: sorry for the difference in the root directories, as I tried multiple projects for "mvn clean install" and only posted the last one that is different from the captured image. None showed failures though, and project imports don't work on any of them.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the cause: some .jar files I put at /Library/Java/Extensions directory yesterday caused InteliJ to be unable to import maven projects. After removing those problematic jar files from /Library/Java/Extensions, IntelliJ import works again!!

thanks everyone

Answer (score -2):

Probably it is stuped, but may be reinstal IteliiJ IDEA?